# Remove trailing whitespace from values in SQL file

Tags: mysql, whitespace

I am  getting a monthly delivery of an SQL file from a 3rd party company, which I then easily load up into a MySQL database and I'm off and running. Except virtually every `VARCHAR` field has extra trailing whitespace, across all 80+ tables.

Example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Aspiration`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `Aspiration` (
  `AspirationID` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `AspirationName` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AspirationID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
-- Dumping data for table `Aspiration`
--

LOCK TABLES `Aspiration` WRITE;
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Aspiration` DISABLE KEYS */;
INSERT INTO `Aspiration` VALUES (1,'-                             '),(5,'Naturally Aspirated           '),(6,'Turbocharged                  '),(7,'Supercharged                  '),(9,'Turbo/Supercharged            '),(10,'Turbo/Intercooled             '),(12,'Turbo/Aftercooled             ');
/*!40000 ALTER TABLE `Aspiration` ENABLE KEYS */;
```

I know  methods to recursively trim the fields after importing the SQL file, however I know there has to be a better way. Ideally, is there a setting that might be producing this on SQL dump that I can tell them to change?

If not, and this is actually their data (which wouldn't shock me), is there any simple method of applying the `trim()` on data load?

Currently my *best* solution is to open the SQL file in Ruby and `gsub(/ +\'/, "\'")` the file.

Comment: Why don't you ask the 3rd party company to fix it? Like, why instead of fixing the roots you fix the consequences?

Comment: Agreed that they need to fix it, but I'm thinking that it might be something about their database that is adding the whitespace on the sql dump. I have my suspicion there because of how consistent it is, like most fields seem to get the whitespace up to their field length. I've seen stranger things for sure. Being able to tell them 'this is what is wrong' is better than telling them 'please go find it'.
The gsub works, and the file size drops by 14mb, about 20%.

Comment: "but I'm thinking that it might be something about their database that is adding the whitespace on the sql dump" --- that's what they store. Mysql does not put bits here and there randomly. If there are spaces in a string in the database - then someone has put it there explicitly. "this is what is wrong" --- it's not wrong, it is the exact data they have put in their database.